# Reading a file, replacing script tags

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been working on this for the greater portion of the day, it's time to seek help.

I am in the process of creating a script that runs after webpack builds a dist folder.  I am using a server framework that **doesn't** allow script tags in the html.

After webpack builds the dist folder, I am taking the folder and creating a new folder to deploy.  I want to manipulate the html file from my webpack folder that loads in most of my javascript and uses the "script-like" tag I can use on the server framework I am using.

This is what it looks like:

Webpack file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Proof of Concept</title>
  </head>
  <body>    
    <div id="app" />
    <script src='./project/client-js.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I need to remove the script tags and make it this instead:

File I need to create to deploy:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Proof of Concept</title>
  </head>
  <body>    
    <div id="app" />
    <?!= include('client-js.js') ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

My idea is to

- read in the webpack dist files using node's `fs.readFile`
- find all the script tags in the html file,
- parse out the src strings with the filenames,
- remove the script tags from the file/string
- insert the syntax I need to use with my server framework for all my js files.

I've spent most of the day trying to re-create the steps I listed.  I've tried reg-ex's to find all the script tags (unfortunately I am not a guru with regex), splitting my string into an array, ultimately, I can't come up with a solution.

If anyone can express their ideas or thoughts on how to solve this, I'd greatly appreciate it.  This is the last step of the build process I need.

Comment: Is your webpack dist file stripped of whitespace (compressed), or does it actually look like the example you posted?

Comment: The HTML isn't stripped, only the javascript files are minified.

Comment: I already have a solution for my js files. I have to deploy them inside of <script> tags.  I am reading all of the files, getting the minified js, and concatenating an opening script tag at the front and a closing script tag at the end of each file.  The last piece of my puzzle is to replace the script tags in my html files with the format displayed in the post. after that, I should be able to deploy while keeping my local dev environment functioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build tools are specifically made to do this sort of tasks; Using [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) is as easy as the following:

Install gulp globally:

```
npm install gulp-cli -g
```

cd to your project dir and install `gulp` and `gulp-html-replace`:

```
npm install gulp gulp-html-replace --save-dev
```

make a `gulpfile.js`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var htmlreplace = require('gulp-html-replace');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  gulp.src('index.html')
    .pipe(htmlreplace({
      js: {
        src: 'client-js.js', // Also could be an array: ['1.js', '2.js']
        tpl: "<?!= include('%s') ?>"
      }
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));
});
```

And run `gulp`. Done.

---

The following index.html (note two comments added this region will be replaced):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Proof of Concept</title>
  </head>
  <body>    
    <div id="app" />
    <!-- build:js -->
    <script src='./project/client-js.js'></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
  </body>
</html>
```

will becomes: (and your `index.html` page is ready under *build* folder):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Proof of Concept</title>
  </head>
  <body>    
    <div id="app" />
    <?!= include('client-js.js') ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

See [gulp-html-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-replace) for more advanced examples